# Parse JS SDK: relation.add() not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I need to add objects to relation in Parse JS SDK, but I can't make `relation.add()` work, I can't find differences between my code and examples from docs or answers I googled. My function:

```
addTagsToProduct(productId, tags) {
        console.log(productId);
        console.log(tags);
        let query = new this.cloud.parse.Query('Products');
        query.equalTo('objectId', productId);
        query.first().then((product) => {
            console.log(product);
            product.relation('tags').query().find().then((productTags) => {
                console.log(productTags);
                let productTagIds = productTags.map((tag) => {
                    return tag.id;
                });

                tags.forEach((tag) => {
                    console.log('checking', tag);
                    if (productTagIds.indexOf(tag) === -1) {
                        console.log('adding', tag);
                        let query = new this.cloud.parse.Query('Tags');
                        query.equalTo('objectId', productId);
                        query.first().then((tag) => {
                            console.log('found', tag);
                            console.log('relation', product.relation('tags'));

                            product.relation('tags').add(tag);
                            product.relation('tags').save({useMasterKey: true}).then((product) => {
                                console.log('saved', product);
                                product.relation('tags').query().find().then((productTags) => {
                                    console.log(productTags);
                                });
                            });
                        }).catch((err) => {
                            console.error(err);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }
```

And `console.log()`'s output from it:

```
pJ1B9mE34k // product ID
["pJ1B9mE34k", "pJ1B9mg34k"] // tags to add
ParseObject {_objCount: 8, className: "Products", id: "pJ1B9mE34k"} // found product
[ParseObject] // tags already added to relation (manually)
checking pJ1B9mE34k // already added tag
checking pJ1B9mg34k // new tag
adding pJ1B9mg34k // found out it's new, adding
found ParseObject {_objCount: 10, className: "Tags", id: "pJ1B9mE34k"} // found tag by id
relation ParseRelation {parent: ParseObject, key: "tags", targetClassName: "Tags"} // relation to add new object to
saved ParseObject {_objCount: 8, className: "Products", id: "pJ1B9mE34k"} // .then() of save() function
[ParseObject] // one relation, the same as before, new one wasn't saved
```

I think I'm missing some minor details, but I really can't find out what are these, so any help'll be very appreciated.
Parse version from `package.json`: `~1.9.2`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors in console, that's strange, because it looks like all `catch()`'es are in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use

```
let productTagsRelations = product.relation("tags");
productTagsRelations.add(tag);
product.save();
```

Instead of

```
product.relation('tags').save();
```

Because the tags is a relational array - is a column - in the product document.
So you have to deal with the products object Itself. not the tags col.